# CoreAudio PublicUtility on Xcode 4.3.1 iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I've an app using low level CoreAudio C functions, usually located under /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/. Just installed Xcode 4.3.1 and iOS 5.1 and Public Utility seems gone away.
My missing files are:
CADebugMacros.h
CAMath.h
CAStreamBasicDescription.cpp
CAStreamBasicDescription.h
Anyone knows if these files have been removed from this last release or should I just copy the files from previous Xcode version?
CoreAudio Public Utility has been there since iOS 2 (at least).

Ty!

Comment: I don;t have them in the SDK but they are in the Apple examples SpeakHere and AurioTouch2 - in an iPublicUtility folder

Comment: Ty TOD, I have'em too. But they used to come updated with every SDK new version. I'll try with the files from the previous SDK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is explained in the [Xcode 4.3 what's new documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW1).

Choose this menu:

```
Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...
```

and download "Audio Tools for Xcode".

Comment: Kurt, exactly as you stated. Works like a charm. Ty!!

Comment: All this seems to get you is canned OSx applications -- no source.

Answer (score 8):

Better place to get them is directly from the Apple Sample Code Reference Library.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html

Sample code links in the RefLib. also provides versioning and modification history information which is helpful allowing you to stay current if there's any bug fixes with these sources.

Apple appears to be updating all their Audio samples to contain whatever subset of public utility is required by each sample, but if you want it all (and I suggest that you do as it's oozing with goodness), grab it from the above link.